# Sending multiple return values in python and get in android using chaquopy

Tags: android, python-3.x, chaquopy

Is it possible to get multiple values in android which is sent by python class using Chaquopy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a Python function returns multiple values (using the `return a, b, c` syntax), it's actually returning a tuple. The easiest way to access the individual values in Java or Kotlin is to use [`PyObject.asList`](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java/com/chaquo/python/PyObject.html#asList--).